# Performing SQL updates in single statements vs batches

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

I'm working with large databases and need advice on how to optimize my selects/updates. Here's an ex:

```
create table Book (
   BookID int,
   Description  nvarchar(max)
)
-- 8 million rows

create table #BookUpdates (
   BookID int,
   Description  nvarchar(max)
)
-- 2 million rows
```

Let's assume that there's 8 million Books and I have to update the genre for 2 million of them.

Problem: the time to run these updates is very long. It will occasionally cause blocking for the users who are also trying to run statements off the database. I've come up with a solution but want to know if there's a better one out there. I have to prepare one-off random updates like this alot (for whatever reason)

```
-- normal update
update b set b.Description = bu.Description
from Book b
join #BookUpdates bu
   on bu.BookID = b.BookID

-- batch update
while (@BookID < @MaxBookID)
begin
   update b set b.Description = bu.Description
   from Book b
   join #BookUpdates bu
      on bu.BookID = b.BookID
   where bu.BookID >= @BookID
      and bu.BookID < @BookID + 5000

   set @BookID = @BookID + 5000
end
```

The second update works a lot faster. I like this solution because I can print status updates to myself on how long it has left and it doesn't cause performance issues on our customers.

**Question: am I missing something important here? Indexes on the temp tables?**

I updated the EXAMPLE tables so I don't get more normalization comments. Only 1 description per book :)

Comment: Which RDBMS are we talking about? SQL Server as it looks, but just to be sure. Could you show a query plan for the update as it is now?

Comment: SQL Server. I don't have a query plan so maybe I'll repost question when I do. Our databases are just really slow so it takes a while to find the BookIDs. Would an index help?

Comment: Indexes on both join IDs almost always help speed things up, but hard to say for sure without seeing the actual plan.

Comment: What do you do with the bookUpdate table after you update the main table? Do you clear out the updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent blocking on the query side by using `NOLOCK` or `READUNCOMITTED` hints on the SQL queries.

The real issue with performance is probably the accumulation of changes in the log.  Your method of batching the changes in groups of 5,000 is quite reasonable.  Because you are setting up the updates in a batch table, you might as well calculate the batch number in the table and then do the looping based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try your own suggestion first and index the temp table before you run the update:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_BookID ON #BookUpdates(BookID)
```

Try it with the index and without the index and see what the impact on the runtime is. If you want to avoid impacting your users for this test, run it outside working hours (if you can) or copy Book to another temp table first and test against that.

Regardless, given the volume, I expect you will still cause blocking for other processes. If you are unable to schedule your updates at a time when no other processes are running against this table (which would be the ideal solution), your existing batch update appears to be a perfectly valid solution. Indexing the temp table will likely help with that too so you may be able to increase the batch size without causing blocking.